# Unity Debug Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, getter-setter

I am trying to create a 2D hit ball game. I want to access an int variable (public int ScoreTask = 10;) which locates in another script. However, when I debug the code, I get these errors:

> error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and
> new object expressions can be used as a statement
>
> error CS0103: The name `ScoreTask' does not exist in the current
> context

Here is my script:

```
public class Countdown : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    private Ball scoreScript;
    public GameObject ScoreBoard;

    void Start () 
    {
        scoreScript = ScoreBoard.GetComponent<Ball> ();
    }
    void Update () 
    {
        GetScore ();
    }
    void GetScore() 
    {
        scoreScript.ScoreTask;

        if (timeLeft == 0 && ScoreTask != 0)
            Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do:

```
void GetScore() 
{
    if (timeLeft == 0 && scoreScript.ScoreTask != 0){
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
    }
}
```

The issue is that you were asking what `ScoreTask` was in your `if` condition, but it doesn't know what `ScoreTask` is without the context of where it comes from, i.e. `scoreScript.ScoreTask`

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I am new to OOP and I considered that I should define it like as a variable.

Comment: You can do it that way as well, for instance `int score = scoreScript.ScoreTask` and then `if (timeleft == 0 && score != 0){`, to store it in a temporary variable named "score" and then compare that.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you want it store it as a variable:

```
void GetScore() 
{
    int scoreTask = scoreScript.ScoreTask;
//  ^^^ because we are "declaring" or creating the variable, we have to specify what 
//      type of variable it is. That is the only time we have to do that. 

    if (timeLeft == 0 && scoreTask != 0)
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
}
```

Another option:

```
private int ScoreTest { get { return scoreScript.ScoreTask; } }
//          ^^^ This is a property, and is effectively a function. 
// It's body will get called everytime someone tries to read its value

void GetScore() 
{
    if (timeLeft == 0 && ScoreTask != 0)
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
}
```

The advantage over a property over a field is that, if I did stored the score value in `scoreTask` and `scoreScript.ScoreTask` changes, I now have the wrong value stored in `scoreTask` because all I have is a *copy* of the original value, so I would have to update `scoreTask` everytime I want to use it to make sure I'm not using outdated values.

However, properties, in this usage, will always give the most up to date value without us having to worry. Also:

```
void Test()
{
    scoreScript.ScoreTask = 0;
    int scoreTask = scoreScript.ScoreTask;

    scoreTask = 1;
    Debug.Log(scoreScript.ScoreTask);     // prints 0
    Debug.Log(scoreTask);                 // prints 1
}
```

All we did is change the value of the *copy*, but not the value of the original. The property I showed you prevents you from actually setting the value and throws a compile error. This is good if no classes have any buisness setting the value. But if we did:

```
int ScoreTask
{
    get { return { scoreScript.ScoreTask; }
    set { scoreScript.ScoreTask = value;  } 
}
```

Now, if we do `ScoreTask = 1;` it will actually change the original value.